# Python updating values within a nested loop and matrix

Tags: python

I have here a nested loop that I cannot figure out for the life of me. In a matrix, if the value of i is divisible by 10, it should add the value of ends1 and ends2 by 10. However, when it reaches the else block, the values are not updated. This is supposed to be an elementary problem but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

update: this function accepts a 2d list/matrix. Also updated code to make it work

In the updated snippet, if you were to run the code, and input 21, the ends1 or ends2 in the else block does not add 10. The code only works for inputs that are divisible by 10+1 (e.g. 11, 21, 31, etc.)

```
inputs = int(input ('Enter number of rows and columns: '))
n = inputs
m = inputs
start_time = time.time()
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(m)] 

#populate coordinates divisible by 10

def terrain_inter(M):
    
    #populate vertical coordinates that are aligned with those coordinates are divisible by 10
    for i in range(len(M)):
        ends1 = 0
        ends2 = 10
        for j in range (len(M)):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            elif i % 10 == 0:
                ends1 = i - 10
                ends2 = i
                print(ends2)
            else:
                    print(ends1)
                    M[i][j] = M[ends1][j] + ((i-ends1)/(ends2 - ends1)) * (M[ends2][j] - M[ends1][j])
                    M[i][j] = round(M[i][j],2)


    for row in M:
       print(*row)
terrain_inter(Matrix)
```

results if input is 21; first line is ends1 which is 0 even if it shouldve been 10 once it reached (10,0)

[image]

Comment: is `M` a numpy matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by "update the value of ends1 and ends2 by 10"? Add 10, subtract, something else?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Hi just edited it in. its only a 2d list

Comment: @Gameplay sorry shouldve specified it better. It should add by 10

Comment: When I copy/paste your code, I get an error because the variable `M` is undefined. Please [edit] your question to update your code so that it does not cause any errors other than what you are asking about. Also describe show the result of running your code and describe how it differs from what you want.

Comment: is `M` a square matrix?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Hi, updated the code block right now sorry about that.

Comment: @dudung yes it is a square matrix whose dimensions is divisible by 10+1 (e.g. 11, 21, 31, etc.)

Comment: @honj-t from your code it is possible that user will input different values for `m` and `n`, right?

Comment: When you run this code, what is the output? And what do you want it to be instead?

Comment: @dudung no, n and m are always the same, i just left it as is with n and m being equal to the input by the user

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it shows a matrix with populated columns if the column is divisible by 10.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual output rather than a description of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're resetting the `ends1` and `ends2` every time you iterate over next row/column.

Suggestions:

- Move initialization of `ends1` and `ends2` out of the loop
- Don't use `i` if you only want to add 10 (as you specified in the comment)
- <s>Calculate the `len(M)` once</s> (doesn't apply anymore since you are editing the question)
- Get rid of either `m` or `n` since they are the same in your implementation
- stop editing the question, please...

```py
ends1 = 0
ends2 = 10
for i in range(len(M)):
    for j in range (len(M[0])):
        if i % 10 == 0 and i>0:
            ends1 += 10
            ends2 += 10
            print(ends2)
        else:
            M[i][j] = M[ends1][j] + ((i-ends1)/(ends2 - ends1)) * (M[ends2][j] - M[ends1][j])
            M[i][j] = round(M[i][j],2)
```

Comment: I agree with @Gameplay. While answering, the question is also altering :-).

Comment: Hi, sorry about the edits. Some comments have been suggesting me to update the question a few times so I had to comply to make it more understandable. In any case, I tried your suggestion but ends1 and ends2 at some point resulted in errors due to it being out of range

Comment: Ok, when I was answering the requirement was to add 10 to those variables, now it chagned. I'll wait for the final version and edit my answer then. It's a bit too time consuming to adjust after every question edit. In general if you are using some calculated values instead of `i` and `j` which are your iterators (and those are guaranteed to not get out of range) you have to either trim / guarantee those values are in range on your own OR wrap it in `try...except` and continue / pass / do something else if the exception occurs.

Comment: Hi, I think this is the finalized question for now. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

If `i` for row and `j` for column, it should be something like

```py
for i in range(len(M)):
    ends1 = 0
    ends2 = 10
    for j in range (len(M[0])):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        elif i % 10 == 0:
            ends1 = i - 10
            ends2 = i
            print(ends2)
        else:
            M[i][j] = M[ends1][j] + ((i-ends1)/(ends2 - ends1)) * (M[ends2][j] - M[ends1][j])
            M[i][j] = round(M[i][j],2)
```

In given code it works only when number of columns is equal to number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
ends1 = 0
ends2 = 10
for i in range(len(M)):
    for j in range (len(M)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        elif i % 10 == 0 and j == len(M)-1:
            ends2 += 10
            ends1 += 10
            print(ends1)
        else:
            M[i][j] = M[ends1][j] + ((i-ends1)/(ends2 - ends1)) * (M[ends2][j] - M[ends1][j])
            M[i][j] = round(M[i][j],2)
```

- Moved ends1 and ends2 outside of loop
- added `j == len(M)-1` to elif block to ensure that both ends are added by 10